# HTML Entity Escape Code showing in Wordpress Title using PWA

Tags: wordpress, unicode

I have a Wordpress site, therobinreport.com, and for our mobile site we are using a PWA plug-in from Appticles.com to transform our content to reside in a PWA when users are on a mobile device.

My problem is that when users view an article on their mobile device, instead of an ellipsis (...) I am getting the actual characters in the title like

```
"&#8230;"
```

if you go to the site and click on the first article you will see what I mean. I am not quite clear on "Escapes" in html and how this stuff works.

Any idea how I can remove this and get it to display correctly? I am familiar with html and css but a not really a programmer.

Thanks to anyone that can give me insight into this - my boss is on my case!!!

Comment: Are you getting 3 separate characters instead of a single ellipsis? Because it sounds like it's just different fonts and they look slightly different?

Comment: No - I am actually getting the characters - sorry - it didn't display here - I forgot to post it as code

    &#8320;

that is what is displaying

Comment: I see. It's a misunderstanding because all characters are unicode characters ;). That's a HTML entity / escape code. Sounds like something is being incorrectly escaped and I can't really help with that.

Comment: Ok thanks - I didn't realize what it was called - should I change the title of my post?